# Three.js creating geometry and mesh freezes animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am trying to create a scrolling text animation, and add more text to the animation while it is running.

This is my function for creating the text geometry and mesh:

```
function createText(){
  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Some new text that as quite long", {

    size: 20,
    height: height,
    font: font

  });

  textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x112358 } ) );

  textMesh1.position.x = (window.innerWidth / 2) + 100;
  textMesh1.position.y = ((window.innerHeight / 2) * -1) + 40;
  textMesh1.position.z = 0;

  textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
  textMesh1.rotation.y = 0;

  group.add( textMesh1 );
}
```

And this is my animate function:

```
function animate() {

    var fistBox = new THREE.Box3();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );


    for(i = 0; i < group.children.length; i++){
      group.children[i].position.x -= 2;
    }

    fistBox.setFromObject(group.children[0]);

    if(group.children[0].position.x < ((window.innerWidth / 2) * -1) - fistBox.size().x ){
      scene.remove( group.children[0] );
    }

    render();

  }
```

Basically the animation scrolls all the children of the group, and when the child leaves the screen it is removed.

The problem is that when I call the function that creates the text geometry and mesh (even without adding it to the group), the scroll animation freezes for a few frames.

I have looked at Web Workers, to try and "multithread" the create function, but it cannot pass back the mesh so I can't use that method to resolve the issue.

Any suggestions on how to create the text geometry and mesh, without effecting the animation, would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You could split your text into chunks (e.g. words are mabye letters) and distribute the creation of word meshes across frames. Something like

```
function TextBuilder( text, opts, parent ) {
    this.words = text.split( /\s/g );
    this.index = 0;
    this.step = function () {
        if ( this.index >= this.words.length ) return;

        var word = this.words[ this.index ];
        ++this.index;
        var geo = new THREE.TextGeometry( word, opts );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, opts.material );
        // need to position mesh according to word length here
        parent.add( mesh );
    }
}
```

then create a textbuilder and call `textbuilder.step()` in animate. The positioning might be an issue though, unless your font is monospace. Otherwise you'll probably have to dig further into [FontUtils](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/FontUtils.js) to see how spacing is done there, and somehow apply that to the textbuilder.